# get a list of nearby location stored in the database compared to my current position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, jquery-mobile

i use a jQuery mobile and html5  and i want to have the list of nearby(variable fixed) location stored in my data base  compared to my current position ,
should i use the function ComputeDistanceBetween??and the select how?
please i need a help
this my try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry">        </script>
</head>
 <body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="getLocation()" id="demo">get current location</button>
<button onclick="console.log(distance)">get ditance from current location to other location</button>

<script>


    var x=document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function(position) {
             var latLngA = new     google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
              var latLngB = new google.maps.LatLng(40.778721618334295,             -73.96648406982422);
            var distance =                
    google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween
   (latLngA, latLngB);
            alert(distance);//In metres
        },
        function() {
            alert("geolocation not supported!!");
        }
  );
   }
    </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

i need to compare with all my list in the data base not with a one point fix

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with very small amounts of data then you could query all data points in your database and compare the distance then select the one that minimizes the distance. This is **VERY INEFFICIENT** if you have anything but a few data points.

A better solution might be to divide your geographic points into quadrants and store the quadrant information along with the points into the database.

Then, when you want to find points that are close to a given point, you compute the quadrant from the point in question and query the database for all points in the quadrant. Then, you just compare the ones in that quadrant.

**UPDATE**

Another important fact you forgot to mention is what is your database back-end. This is important because for instance, if you use SQL Server 2008 or newer it has [built-in support for spatial data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd434647.aspx). You may want to look into this..

Comment: thks for help,but how i could query all data in my database?with bouclage for?!!

Comment: What type of database is it? Where is it stored? And do you have a back-end for your mobile website?